# Anyone used libvlc on Mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, vlc, libvlc

**Edit**

I've been able to simplify the reproduction of the error:

When trying to build this [sample](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial):

```
$ cc example.c -arch i386 -lvlc.2 -L/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/  -I/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/include/ -o example
$ ./example 
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/lib/libvlc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/francis/src/playground/libvlc/./example
```

**Original Post**

I am experiencing the following behavior:

- Create new XCode project (Cocoa or command line tool)
- Link with `libvlc.2.dylib` found in `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib`
- Run the application
- => Crashes with stack-trace pointing pointing to `__dyld_dyld_fatal_error` at the top and `__dyld__dyld_start` at the bottom.

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe I need to link with a fresh VLC build, but I haven't yet succeeded building it on Snow Leopard and the MacPort doesn't work as well (fails during build phase).

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with otool -L if your programm is correctly linked with all your libs.

relink every dylib with install_name_tools