# Compiling C++ with libvlc on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, libvlc

I am trying to compile/build a code in C++ on Mac, using **OpenCV** and **libvlc**.

I was trying to accomplish that using XCode, but I got the same error as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756062/anyone-used-libvlc-on-mac) and couldn't solve.

So I tried to compile on Terminal, using `gcc -lvlc main.cpp`  but now I got this error:

> ld: library not found for -lvlc
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any ideas on how to link the library correctly? How to see the clang error? If so please try to be really clear, because I am a newbie - I couldn't reproduce the answer from the linked topic using *otool*.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `gcc main.cpp -lvlc`

Comment: Already tried and got the same problem :(

Comment: How did you install OpenCV (homebrew? from source? a dmg?), and where did you install it? How did you install libvlc and where did you install it? Do you want to use static or dynamic libraries? If static, you'll need to find `vlc.o` and tell the compiler where it is with the `-L` flag, or if dynamic you'll need to locate `vlc.dylib`....

Comment: Mark's response above is on track. Have you also looked into installing the library with macports? You can install both OpenCV, and possible livvlc using it. However, sounds like you need to add the link directory to where your libvlc library is located with -L.